# Get input value with Javascript only when the input is changed

Tags: javascript, forms, input, upload, dom-events

**I Have this code:**

```
<script>
  var loadFile = function(event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('imagePreviewer');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };
</script>
```

That is taking the input from a file upload field and inserts the file path to the src attribute of an image element with the "imagePreviewer" id.

**The Problem is:** When the page loads it changes the src of the image to "null". I need to make this function work only when the user uploads the file...

Now I tried different ways and *couldn't got it working* so I would really appreciate some help with that!

Comment: How are you using `loadFile`? If you only want it executed when a user picks a file, just set it as the change event listener on your file input, and don't call it anywhere else.

Comment: I'm quite stupid and don't really know javascript, can you write me the code you would use?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what do you what the user to see while he didn't choose an image. I see 2 ways:

1. If you want to show an empty box, you may show a css-styled `div` element with some background, or simply no-image-selected-picture (like http://allensguide.com/img/no_image_selected.gif), and change the `src` when the user selects an image.
2. You may not to show the preview box at all until the user selects an image.

Comment: Is it what you wanted?

Comment: No. There is an image in the first place there. i want that image to change (the src will change) only when the user upload an image...

Comment: Please, tell us the concrete action, after which the `src` must be changed. Do you want to change `src` only after the server received image? Or after pressing some button?..

Comment: After the user pressed the "upload file" button, choose an image file and clicked "open" in the dialog box.